# Can we use both OpenTok and Jitsi in a single Android project?

Tags: java, android, opentok, jitsi, jitsi-meet

My Android application has OpenTok already. I am trying to add Jitsi to my project.

I'm getting the following build issues:

```
Type org.webrtc.EglBase$Context is referenced as an interface from org.webrtc.EglBase14$Context
```

and

```
Duplicate class org.webrtc.AudioSource found in modules jetified-opentok-android-sdk-2.15.2-runtime.jar (opentok-android-sdk-2.15.2.aar) and jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.75.2-jitsi-2994175-runtime.jar (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.75.2-jitsi-2994175) Duplicate class org.webrtc.AudioTrack found
```

Can I use both and have a switch between OpenTok and Jitsi in a single Android project?

Comment: have you tried doing it ?

Comment: I am trying to do , but I'm getting the following build issues. Type org.webrtc.EglBase$Context is referenced as an interface from `org.webrtc.EglBase14$Context`.

Comment: update your question to include all the relevant information then :) include what you've done and what your problem is specifically

Comment: Duplicate class org.webrtc.AudioSource found in modules jetified-opentok-android-sdk-2.15.2-runtime.jar (opentok-android-sdk-2.15.2.aar) and jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.75.2-jitsi-2994175-runtime.jar (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.75.2-jitsi-2994175)
Duplicate class org.webrtc.AudioTrack found

Comment: Minor formatting edits. Adding informations from the comments in the question body.

Comment: Duplicate class org.webrtc.AudioSource found in modules jetified-opentok-android-sdk-2.15.2-runtime.jar (opentok-android-sdk-2.15.2.aar) and jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.75.2-jitsi-2994175-runtime.jar (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.75.2-jitsi-2994175)                                          This is the error what i am getting while adding open tok and jitsi dependencies

Comment: @Sohail Did you manage to fix this issue?